# Why does the .exe file become locked after compiling?

Tags: c++, compilation, sublimetext, collect

If I compile `Test.cpp` with `g++ -o Hello_World Test.cpp`, I get `Hello_World.exe`. If I run `g++ -o Hello_World Test.cpp` again, I get a collect 2 error:

[image: Collect 2 error during compiling]

The goal is to compile `Test.cpp` into `Hello_World.exe` (but two times in a row). Here are my steps:

1. In a terminal: `g++ -o Hello_World Test.cpp`

- This will successfully create `Hello_World.cpp`

2. Test with `./Hello_World.cpp`

- The program did compile
- I also tried this without this step and had the same error later

3. Compile again: `g++ -o Hello_World Test.cpp`

- This is where the collect 2 error occurs, preventing the file from being compiled.

4. If I right click on `Hello_World.cpp` and try to delete it, I get an error saying `The action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program`. I tried to use `resmon.exe` to see the running `.exe` files, and I couldn't figure out what was using `Hello_World.exe`, and `Hello_World.exe` was not open itself. If I use `rm Hello_World.cpp`, I get an error saying I don't have permission.

If anyone has an idea as to what might be happening, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could be your antivirus.

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't thought of that. I will look into possible solutions to that, thank you! <3

Comment: Could also be your debugger / program still running from the previous run.

Comment: Ok, even if I don't run the program, but just compile it twice in a row, it still gives the error. I am also just using Sublime and mingw64 to compile. I also tried on VS code and Notepad, and I always get the same error. I don't know that much about debuggers though. Is there a way to figure out what debugger I have? Thank you!

Comment: You probably have a problem with your file/directory permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone has an idea as to what might be happening, I would greatly appreciate it.

Well it’s simple. The application is running in the background. You can check your *TaskManager* and kill it from there.

What exactly causes the application to keep running in the background will need more investigation to find out.

---

The most common reason this happens in *Sublime* is when you are running an interactive application. *Sublime* doesn’t forward any input that you type into the output panel to your running program, so it’s effectively hung forever in the background waiting for input you can’t provide.

Comment: In your case, the program isn’t even interactive so our investigation ought to look elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! So I investigated around in the Task Manager, and I didn't see the Hello_World file running, which was strange. Something else I found was really weird. I am on a Macbook Pro running Windows through BootCamp, and I restarted my computer into Apple and did the same procedure above in iterm2, and I was able to overwrite the files just fine, but when switching back to Windows, the error persisted.

Comment: That is not proof that the file wasn’t running on the Mac OS. Mac OS is based on the UNIX operating systems. These operating systems do not lock files that are in use. So you can actually overwrite them while using them. Windows on the other hand locks files so we first have to find the program that is causing the lock of your executable file.

Comment: I also found I can compile a C file twice in a row: (gcc -o CFile Test.c) but if I do g++ -o CPPFile Test.cpp, this will work the first time, but then give a collect 2 error the second time.

Comment: But not `.cpp`? That is definitely a weird behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm quite confused.